# How do I filter objects to be compared using VSDBCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, continuous-deployment, vsdbcmd

I'm trying to automate my deployment and I've be trying to use the VSDBCMD command line tool to compare schemas of my development and staging databases. I can get it to work comparing everything but what I can't figure out is how to filter out the objects I want to be compared. At the moment it compares everything which means it wants to add or remove users, full text catalogs, file groups etc.

Basically I just want to compare tables, stored procedures, views, functions and a few other things. From within visual studio you can set what objects to compare but I can't see from the documentation how to do this using the command line tool.

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. The best explanation I have seen is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/75656877-95e1-4c13-8540-8a445f47ca57

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my workstation now, but I believe that it is possible to filter out user scripts by checking the "ignore permissions" option in the db settings file. You might try experimenting with the other ignore settings to see if you can get closer to your goal that way.